# autofill fill database field by 50% based on another database field's data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a  fields by 50% of what another field has in database 
Table

field1 (40,000) get it value from a form submitted

field2 (#)so this field2 will be updated by 50% of what ever is in field1 that is 60 thousand in this case

please any body who can help with the mysql Query.below is the code to insert into field one

```
<?php
session_start(); {

//Include database connection details
include('../../dbconnect.php');

$amount =  strip_tags($_POST['someid']);

//$days = str_replace('/', '-',$_POST['endtime']);

if ($amount == "" ) {
    $_SESSION['ph'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Please Fill The Fields</div></center>";
    header("location: PH.php");
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (amount) VALUES ('$amount')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $_SESSION['ph'] ="<center><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Request Accepted.</div></center>";
   header("location: PH.php");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: So which other field in this table do you want updated to `($amount + ($amount*0.5))`

Comment: An alternative solution would be to create a trigger in your mysql-database, which fills your field automaticly. But in my experience triggers are in specific situations not as good as they sound. So you should know what you do. But for completation it's worth to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$field1amount = $_POST['formid'];
$field2amount = $field1amount + ($field1amount*0.5);

$sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (Field1,Field2) VALUES ('$field1amount','$field2amount');
```

also code is vulnerable to sql injection don't use mysql_ or mysqli_ use pdo and prepared statements.

Comment: Only using Prepared, Parameterised and Bound queries will protect from SQL Injection. Your query would be JUST AS vulnerable to SQL Injection even if run using PDO. Both `mysqli_` and `PDO` can run Prepared, Parameterised and Bound queries

Comment: as i said pdo and prepared statements :) i expect mysqli to be deprecated sooner rather than later in favour of pdo being the only access layer anyway

Comment: No thats the way rumours get started, and there is no suggestion of that that I have found

Comment: no suggestion but i can see it coming infact it almost obvious it'll happen over time anyway but either way this discussion is out of scope for the question and i'd always recommend pdo over mysqli anyway.